# How to make items and blocks automatically enchant?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make some form of machine that makes it so every single block and item in the game has the curse of vanishing on it when I pick it up or it goes in my inventory or just so every single item and block always has it like even in the creative menu.

What could I use to accomplish such a task, whether it be commands, data packs, mods, or plugins?

(EDIT: someone said "why not just clear inventory every time you die" because I want items to also clear from chests and everything too)

Comment: What about a solution using commands and functions, instead of developing a mod?

Comment: How about using the enchant command?

Comment: Why not just use a command to clear each player's inventory when they die? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: Re your edit, per the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/wiki/Curse_of_Vanishing), "The item does not vanish if it is dropped manually, or if it is placed in a chest before death"

Answer (score 0):

You can run this on repeat:

```
/enchant @a curse_of_vanishing
```

But if the player never holds anything then it won't happen, and this also means once you hold an unenchanted item you can never use an enchanting table on it.